# Entering loop if the line doesnt have matching words

Tags: regex, perl

i have three lines in an array as follows:
`@file= ("pin timing missing flow","pin timing adds flow","pin timing no flow");`

I want to enter a loop if the line doesn't have either 'miss' or 'add'. I used the following code:

```
foreach my $file (@file){
      if((!($file=~ m/missing/))or(!($file=~ m/adds/))){...........}
```

but while running the code it enters the loop for all the lines. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have an array with curly braces.

Comment: And even if your code was correct (There's a logic error too), none of those three strings have 'missing' or 'adds' in them...

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues with this:

```
@file= {"pin timing miss flow","pin timing add flow","pin timing no flow"};
```

This assigns a single hashref (With an odd number of elements that if you're using warnings like you should be will generate one) to `@list`. You want parenthesis instead of braces if you want to assign a list to the array.

```
foreach my $file (@file){
    if((!($file=~ m/missing/))or(!($file=~ m/adds/))){...........}
```

This iterates over that single hashref, which stringifies as something like `HASH(0x592a601981e0)`, which obviously doesn't contain either word you want to skip over.

Even if it did, if your string has `"adds"` in it but not `"missing"`, the first condition in the `if` will match and it'll thus succeed. Just use a single regular expression match using alternation (And `$foo !~ /bar/` instead of `! $foo =~ /bar/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

my @file= ("pin timing miss flow","pin timing add flow","pin timing no flow");
foreach my $file (@file) {
    if ($file !~ /\b(?:missing|adds)\b/) {
        say "$file doesn't have either keyword."
    }
}
```

Note the use of `\b` anchors to avoid matching something in the middle of a larger word.

Comment: I don't think word boundaries (aka word breaks), `\b`, are generally referred to as [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html).

Comment: Curiously, "anchor" only shows up twice in [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). I tend to call word boundaries "assertions".

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#Avoid Curly Braces `{` in array
my @file= ("pin timing miss flow","pin timing add flow","pin timing no flow");

my $checkPoint = "miss|add";

foreach my $each(@file)
{
   if($each!~m/($checkPoint)/)
   {
       print "Non-Matched line: $each...\n";
   }
}

Output:
Non-Matched line: pin timing no flow...
```